# How to return to the previous view after loading the uiweb view

Tags: iphone

I'm having a view (lets say view1) that has a button to load an `uiwebview`. After loading the webview I need to show the view1 again.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[myWebView removeFromSuperView];`

If you want to animate easily, you can put the UIWebView in a separate view controller, present it as a modal view controller and run `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in your controller when done.